# Display Bestsellers products first

Tags: magento-enterprise, configurable-product, best-seller

I am trying to show Magento category using bestseller products i.e bestsellers of that category should show first and all i have is configurable products. I tried bestsellers code from google but those seems to work only for simples.

your help is much appreciated

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information. Show the code that works for the simple products. Where did you get the code from? You are not using a extension, for this (just checking)? Is there a reason not to use a extension?

Comment: basically i i have used http://inchoo.net/magento/bestseller-products-in-magento/  to show best sellers in home and the same code used in  product_collection_load_before event to show beste sellers in category page first. Later when i checked its not showing proper results in both places.As my total site has configurable products.I can use an extensions if its free please suggest if any.Finally i need to show best selling products in catageory to display first in list page.

Comment: please add and contribute to this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105698/magento-getting-store-bestsellers-configurable-products-only-from-current-stor and the code that is being created here https://github.com/seansan/SNH_Addorderqty